# Tensorflow: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa

I'm writing Rasa source code for my chatbot, using Python 3.7.7, pip 20.1.1 and conda 4.5.12.
I use the command: `conda install tensorflow` to install this framework, version 2.1.0.
However when trying to execute `rasa train` to train my chatbot, I came up against an error with process of importing tensorflow.
The Error: **ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
I still find the tensorflow folder, so what I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `pip install tensorflow`